# How to send a structure to Unity with Qt

Tags: c#, qt, sockets, unity-game-engine, structure

I want to send a structure in Qt to Unity (C#) by TCP. What confuse me is when I receive the structure at Unity, I get messy code.

How to send and how to receive can I get the correct structure?

Comment: just send Json...

Answer (score 1):

To send data over a byte stream based connection you first have to serialize it. 
For serializing and, on the receiver side deserializing, data into a byte stream you'll need to make sure both sides expect the data in the same format.

There are a lot of them to chose from, e.g. binary based ones like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), or text based ones like JSON.

Comment: You could perhaps elaborate that sending the binary structure is not a valid form of serialization...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I rephrased the text a bit, is this better?